# Password Prompt HTML

Tags: html

So the user clicks on a link that prompts the user for a password. If password is correct, the next page is opened. How would I go about doing that. I know that its `<form><input type = "password".....>` but how do I make it so that the password field appears if you click on the link. This is what I have so far:

```
<li><h3>Education</h3></li>

<a href = "transcript.html"> My SJSU Transcript </a>
```

Also how do I set the password and check to see if the user enters the correct password.

Edit: Unfortunately it all has to be done in html. The password is static.

Comment: JavaScript, my friend, JavaScript... and AJAX for password check if you don't want to expose it (of course you don't)

Comment: `htaccess` could be another option

Comment: Javascript is probably worst option here.

Answer (score 1):

There is a better solution using only HTML & Javascript though it's not simple. You would need to:

- encrypt the contents of the HTML file.
- Ask user for password
- Use password to decrypt and serve HTML file

Here is an implementation [source code](https://github.com/MaxLaumeister/clientside-html-password) & [live demo](https://www.maxlaumeister.com/code/clientside-html-password/).